# Android application crashes while fetching data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from my real time database in Firebase, but it crashes with an exception `cannot cast hash map to string`. I followed many tutorials and alternatives, but nothing works may be because my data base is something like as shown below and my application is unable to pair key and value.

Please help me with this. I have attached my code and the database screenshot below. Thank you in advance.

[image: My firebase database image]

```
public class AlaCarte extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    String arr[]=new String[]{"Paneer Butter Masala","Chicken Butter Masala","Chicken Biriyani"};
    ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
    ArrayList food=new ArrayList();
    Button btn;


    Firebase mref;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ala_carte);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Alacarte!!");

        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);


        DatabaseReference databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Food items");

        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               Iterable<com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot> iterable=dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                Iterator<com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot> it=iterable.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext())
                {
                    com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1=it.next();
                    String catnane=dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                    Iterable<com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot> iterable2=dataSnapshot1.getChildren();
                    Iterator<com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot> it2=iterable2.iterator();
                    while (it2.hasNext())
                    {
                        String proname=dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                        String price=(String)dataSnapshot1.getValue();
                        String item=proname+"   "+price;
                        food.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(AlaCarte.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,food);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                CheckedTextView checkedTextView = ((CheckedTextView) view);
                //checkedTextView.setChecked(!checkedTextView.isChecked());
                if (checkedTextView.isChecked()) {
                    checkedTextView.setChecked(false);
                    al.remove(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
                } else {
                    checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
                    al.add(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
                }

            }
        });
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (al.isEmpty()) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Select check boxes to place your order", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(AlaCarte.this, ConfirmAlacarte.class);
                    i.putExtra("mylist", al);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your logcat output ?

Answer (score 1):

You store the prices as number, but are trying to retrieve them as a string.

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot foodItemsSnapshot) {
  for (DataSnapshot categorySnapshot: foodItemsSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String categoryName = categorySnapshot.getKey();
    for (DataSnapshot foodItemSnapshot: categorySnapshot.getChildren()) {
      String foodItemName = foodItemSnapshot.getKey();
      Integer price = foodItemSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
      String description = foodItemName+"   "+price;
    }
  }
}
```

If this fails on a specific item, it most likely doesn't follow the rules for your data structure. If that is the case, include the JSON of that specific section of the tree in your question. It is much easier to help if you include the JSON as text instead of a screenshot. You can easily get this text by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
String price=(String)dataSnapshot1.getValue()
```

According to the [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot), the **value** could be any of these.

Value returns the data contained in this snapshot as native types. The possible types returned are:

bool

string

long

double

IDictionary{string, object}

List{object} This list is recursive; the possible types for object in the above list is given by the same list. These types correspond to the types available in JSON.

Check before you cast it.

```
Object obj = dataSnapshot1.getValue();
If (obj instanceof String) {
      String price=(String)dataSnapshot1.getValue()
}
```